# How do I maintain the original text structure like spaces or lines position into the database and display it back?

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel, shell-exec

I ran a `$whois` command on one of the intruder IP that got ban on my VM.

[image]

I tried to store the result of that as base64 encode

```
$whois        = 'whois '.$ip;
$whoisDetails = shell_exec($whois);
$details      = base64_encode($whoisDetails);
```

and decode it back on my view when I query

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    <p>{{ base64_decode($vt->details) }}</p>
</li>
```

[image]

Is there something that I should do via :

- HTML : maybe some tags like `pre` or `code`
- CSS : maybe some styles I can apply
- PHP : maybe use diff fn than shell_exec()
- store/query the db

How do I maintain the original text structure like spaces or lines position into the Database and display it back in the view?

Comment: Wrap the output in a `<pre></pre>` tag

Comment: Okay, let me try that now.

Comment: Either wrap it in a <pre> tag or set css `white-space: pre;` on the element that has the data. [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the output in a `<pre>` tag which will retain the formatting

```
<li class="list-group-item">
<p><pre>{{ base64_decode($vt->details) }}</pre></p>
</li>
```